# Why is the return value not what I expected in this C program with macro?

Tags: c, macros, printf

When I run the following code, the return value is 11, but I was expecting it to return 25.  Can someone explain this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SQR(a) a*a

int main()
{
    int i=3;
    printf("%d",SQR(i+2));
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not use abbreviations when you write your question, and tag your question with the name of the programming language when appropriate.

Comment: Macros are not functions.

Comment: Pascal Couq  thank you. Can you answer my another question?? -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442100/there-is-are-2n1-items-in-a-list-of-which-all-are-duplicates-expect-1-item-h

Answer (score 4):

Needs more parentheses.  This:

```
#define SQR(a) a*a
```

expands to this:

```
i+2*i+2
```

which is:

```
3+2*3+2
```

which is 11 because `*` has precedence over `+`.

You need to define your macro like this:

```
#define SQR(a) ((a)*(a))
```

to ensure that this kind of thing doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are not the same as regular functions.

During the reprocessing all macros are replaced exactly by what they are define. In your case, the line:

```
 printf("%d",SQR(i+2));
```

is replaced by the line:

```
 printf("%d", i+2*i+2);
```

So, you see the unexpected result there.

The correct way is:

```
#define SQR(a) ((a)*(a))
```

The preprocessor result will be:

```
printf("%d", ((i+2)*(i+2)));
```

Try to learn on this mistake. Issues of this kind are quite hard to debug.

Comment: Your definition of `SQR` is still buggy, because it will break if you try to do something like `SQR(5) & 0xff`, which will expand to `(5)*(5) & 0x1c`, which is equivalent to `5 * (5 & 0x1c)`, which is not the same as `(5 * 5) & 0x1c`, the intended result. `SQR` should instead be defined like so: `#define SQR(a) ((a)*(a))`, or in fact not defined at all - preprocessor macros that evaluate their arguments more than once are the causes of a frighteningly high number of bugs.